# MS Word - add Appendix listing to table of contents without page number

Tags: microsoft-word

I have an Appendix style defined in Word 365 based on 'Heading 1' style so the appendices to a large document appear in the Table of Contents. However, I do not want to show page numbers of the Appendicies as these attachments come from varied sources and will be inserted as PDFs into the final document (which will be all PDF). I can't seem to find a way to set up a style that will appear in the Table of Contents but not have page numbers listed in the Table of contents

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your TOC field, you just need to set the Appendix level for the TOC to be different to those for your Heading styles (so it uses a different TOC style).

Then you can specify just that TOC level to exclude page numbering by adding the \n switch specifying that level.

For example, in this picture below, Heading 1 and Heading 2 styles are set as level 1 and 2 (ie will use TOC1 and TOC2) respectively, but Appendix is set to be level 3 so will use TOC3 style.

The \n 3-3 tells Word to omit page numbering for level 3 in your TOC (ie TOC3), meaning that other levels (eg 1 and 2) will still have page numbering.

Then just format TOC3 style to be based on TOC1 (if you want it to have same level indent/font etc as your Heading 1 entries in the TOC).

[image]

Comment: OK - I already have four levels of heading so I guess I need to set the Appendix style to heading style 5 but make heading 5 the same style as heading 1? Will give it a try.  Thanks for you reply I had given up on solving this one and had resigned myselt to removing the page numbers from the output PDF

Comment: You don't need to link the Appendix style to Heading 5, but just modify the TOC5 style so it is based on TOC1 style if you want it to look like that in TOC.  And in the TOC field code above where it says "Appendix,3" it would be "Appendix,5" and also change the "\n 3-3" to "\n 5-5" so it hides page numbers for level 5.